# Replacement/Equivalent for the CorBindToRuntimeEx-Function?

Tags: c++

I want to use it to inject C# dll into a process (http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-to-inject-a-managed-assembly-dll/) but the CorBindToRuntimeEx-Function is deprecated...

Is there an equal function for CorBindToRuntimeEx which is not deprecated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [CLRCreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537633(v=vs.100).aspx) instead. [Loading the Common Language Runtime into a Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01918c6x%28VS.100%29.aspx) explains how to do this in CLR v4.0+.